# Alternative way to write triple summation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation-method

I have expression as
$$\sum_{l\in \phi}^{} \sum_{i=1}^{K} \sum_{m\in \phi \setminus l}^{}  a(l,i) b(m,i) c(l,m,i)$$
where $m\in \phi \setminus l$ means excluding $l$.

I would like to write this expression without - excluding $l$. Probably I have to separate this into two parts, however, I really did not get it. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Provided the summand is defined at $m=l$, you can easily convert $\sum_{m\in \phi \setminus l} f(l,m)$ into $\sum_{m\in\phi} f(l,m)\, - f(m,m)$.

Comment: $f(m,m)$ or $f(l,l)$?

Comment: Sorry yes, $f(l,l)$.

Comment: @Erick, thanks, got it.